# Apply pagination on arbitrary List in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, pagination

If you use Spring in your work - you know that sometimes you cannot write a query (JPA or native) giving you all entities you want. In these cases you have to construct a custom collection (List in most cases) with your entities. And then - the problem: pagination. How this functionality in Spring is designed to work on some arbitrary List of some entity class. If I have the List<SomeEntity> - how I should apply a Pageable to it in order to get Page<SomeEntity> with the correct content (properly sorted and paged) ?

Comment: Sure you can write a query that gives you what you need, you have to think about that harder. I haven't come across a situation that I couldn't solve with a query yet. Doing that in a list won't perform and will increase your memory consumption.

Comment: What you would do if you have to GENERATE some long list (needs pagination) - you will generate entities and save them into the database just to be able to query them back from the DB ?

Comment: Your question states you already have the entities and you aren't able to write the query. And yes you want them probably in the database. If your quesiton isn't about persistence entities then please make that clear in your question.

Comment: Yes, my question is (for sure) about the case I have entities in the DB already. But your answer stating that "I can always write the query that gives me what I need" is at least doubtful. Sometimes you need to combine entities, sometimes you need to filter entities, sometimes you need some processing... There might be potentially many many special cases where you cannot just write a query that gives you right away the final collection.

Comment: And why not. SQL is pretty good at joining, filtering etc. and you can easily map the result to a custom DTO. As stated I have rarely had the case I couldn't write a query for my needs. Writing a query actually improved the performance instead of trying to shoehorn this into java and do the procssing and filtering.

Comment: After all - is it possible to apply Pageable to a List and convert it to Page ?

Comment: You can but I would strongly advice against it. You can probably use a `PagedListHolder` from Spring to achieve this, but as stated I cannot urge yyou enough to not use this and go down this path. If the list grows your performance will drop and memory consumption will grow, with excessive large lists this might (and will) even break your application.